# Getting list of route from a hosted laravel website on 000webhost.com

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, deployment, cpanel

I have uploaded the laravel 5 project to the cPanel. This is the link for the hosted project https://unattained-telecomm.000webhostapp.com/
Thank you.

I can get the route list locally using php artisan route:list.

Comment: It would be the same

Comment: Do you mean, I should use the local link to access it?

Comment: Yes. The routes won't change when you upload the project unless you start making changes on the server that you didn't make locally

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the API in this format
domain/api/route

For instance,
https://unattained-telecomm.000webhostapp.com/api/user